# Handling hotfixes when working only with git master branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, cicd, hotfix

I keep reading how people are forgoing the `develop` git branch and doing all work on `master` - and how this makes everything simpler.

I tried it:

- I have a master branch (with linear history) and many short-lived feature branches.
- I merge features into master.
- To release, I tag a commit on master - e.g. `staging` or `1.2.3` - to trigger my CI/CD tool to produce a staging or production release, respectively.

That works nicely... until one needs to release a hotfix.

Suppose I prepare a hotfix and merge it into main. There would be feature commits (`feat`) between the last stable release (`1.2.3`) and the hotfix (`hotfix`) - and if I deploy that last commit, it'll include all those miscellaneous features as well:

```
1.2.3 <-- feat <-- feat <-- feat <--hotfix
```

That's asking for trouble.

How does one deal with hotfixes in such a workflow?

Comment: Libraries make use of maintenance branches based on the tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222038/appropriate-method-for-making-a-bugfix-to-older-version-tags-of-a-repo/72222390#72222390

For deploying apps, a true CI/CD workflow would be to deploy much more frequently so that a hotfix is unnecessary. New code or features that haven't been fully QA'ed can be hidden behind feature flags.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

1. Use a release (or hotfix) branch that you will discard later - see here for details - https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/ . Note here that if you make this your standard pattern and you use SemVer as in your question, the recommended way is to have each release branch on its own minor to avoid versioning collisions - see my post here for details - https://worklifenotes.com/2019/01/20/semver-in-production-always-keep-separate-production-branch-on-its-own-minor/
2. Roll forward with feature flags as suggested in the other comment - see my post here for details - https://worklifenotes.com/2022/11/02/on-feature-flags/

This may be a lot of information to go through, but these options if properly adopted should be enough to deal with any real-life situation.

Comment: Thanks. You're right it's a lot to go through. I was hoping for a tl;dr but these things are never easy! :)